# osx locale bug?

Tags: c++, macos, locale

I want to port our application (which works on Windows, Linux, Solaris, AIX, etc.), but I have a lot of problem with locale. This code works on all platforms, except OSX:

```
#define SIZE 1000

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{    
    char dest[SIZE];
    wchar_t *dptr = L"árvíztűrőtükörfúrógép";
    size_t count = SIZE;
    size_t length;

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

    length = wcstombs(dest, dptr, count);
    printf("%d characters were converted.\n", length);
    printf("The converted string is \"%s\"\n\n", dest);
}
```

Please, help me guys, to print that text in terminal in ISO-8859-2 encoding!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps you should also describe how it fails? What do you get after the conversion call?

Comment: When terminal encoding is UTF-8 and LC_CTYPE is "C", everythings OK, but when terminal encoding is Central European (ISO Latin 2) and LC_CTYPE is "hu_HU.ISO8859-2", I get this: -1 characters were converted.
The converted string is "árvízt". It fails on "ő" and "ű" characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple Macintosh uses neither ISO 8859-1 nor ISO 8859-2 encoding. Instead, Apple uses proprietary code tables, namely MacRoman for West European and MacCentralEuropean for East European Languages. WWW browsers on Macintosh (Netscape Navigator 2 and above, and Microsoft Internet Explorer 2.1) automatically perform the recoding from ISO 8859 encoding used on Internet to Macintosh native character set.

Taken from here: http://nl.ijs.si/gnusl/cee/iso8859-2.html

Here's what you need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman

And here's the UTF-8 <-> MacRoman conversion code: http://alienryderflex.com/utf-8/

There are only the modifiers for "u" and "o" (inserted after these letters) to get the "ő" and "ű" characters.

See the table here http://www.alanwood.net/demos/macroman.html

"˝", Code=0xFD, U+02DD, "double acute accent", Spacing Modifier Letters

("Think different" in action)

Comment: Thanks, but the biggest problem with MacRoman and Latin 1 is they don't contain "ő" and "ű" characters.

Comment: You missed that: double acute accent is a separate symbol. The console's' text "renderer" attaches this to the previous letter.

Comment: This is similar to the double-dot for swedish/finnish keyboards in DOS

Comment: Thanks a lot Viktor. It seems I have to forgot the ISO8859-2 support in our application...